# How to find duplicates in pyspark dataframe using hash md5 method?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two input dataframes as below and I want to find the duplicate rows using the hash method.

Input dataframe 1: df1

```
|a |b |c |
|5 |2 |3 |
|1 |5 |4 |
|1 |5 |3 |
```

Input dataframe 2: df2

```
|a |b |c |
|5 |2 |3 |
|5 |2 |3 |
|1 |5 |4 |
|1 |5 |3 |
```

Preparing the col_list and finding the hash on input columns

```
col_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df1 = df1.withColumn("hash", md5(concat_ws('+', *col_list)))
df2 = df2.withColumn("hash", md5(concat_ws('+', *col_list)))

upd: df1               upd: df2
|a |b |c |hash  |      |a |b |c |hash  |
|5 |2 |3 |sfsd23|      |5 |2 |3 |sfsd23|    
|1 |5 |4 |fsd345|      |5 |2 |3 |sfsd23|
|1 |5 |3 |54sgsr|      |1 |5 |4 |fsd345|
                       |1 |5 |3 |54sgsr|

df_diff = df1.select(df1.hash).substract(df2.select(df2.hash))
```

### df_diff.show()  -- Nothing

---

It is not showing the difference as the hash is matching the 1 record of hash value from df1 and 2 records of same hash value with df2 are same.
But, how to find the dulicate in this after, then I want to raise some error once if I find.

Comment: you could try a left anti join on the has column `df_diff = df1.join(df2, ['hash'], 'left_anti')`

Comment: But, you will get all the four rows, so you want me to find the duplicate check after that???

Comment: left_anti - gives the same result as subtract.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`.exceptAll`** **(from Spark-2.4+)** instead of `.substract` as `.exceptAll` preserves all duplicated rows by using df2 as source dataframe.

**`From docs:`**

[**subtract:**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract)

```
Return a new DataFrame containing rows in this DataFrame but not in another DataFrame.

This is equivalent to EXCEPT DISTINCT in SQL.
```

[**exceptAll:**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll)

```
Return a new DataFrame containing rows in this DataFrame but not in another DataFrame while preserving duplicates.

This is equivalent to EXCEPT ALL in SQL.
```

**`Example:`**

**`From Spark-2.4+:`**

```
df2.exceptAll(df1).show(10,False)
#+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
#|a  |b  |c  |hash                            |
#+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
#|5  |2  |3  |747d9c66398e89fbda6570f6bf945ed6|
#+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
```

**`For Spark<2.4:`**

We need to use Spark **`window row_number functi`on** then left join to find the duplicated records.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql import Window

w=Window.partitionBy(*['a', 'b', 'c', 'hash']).orderBy(lit(1))


df1=df1.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w))
df2=df2.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w))

df2.alias("d2").join(df1.alias("d1"),(df1["a"]==df2["a"]) & (df1["b"]==df2["b"]) & (df1["c"]==df2["c"]) & (df1["hash"]==df2["hash"]) & (df1["rn"]==df2["rn"]),'left').\
filter(col("d1.rn").isNull()).\
select("d2.*").\
drop("rn").\
show()

#+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
#|a  |b  |c  |hash                            |
#+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
#|5  |2  |3  |747d9c66398e89fbda6570f6bf945ed6|
#+---+---+---+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, the exceptAll has there from spark 2.4 release. But, we are still using 2.3.* version. So exceptALL is not working? Anyother way we can do this. Your idea is perfect,  but the version kills us.

Comment: @Rocky1989, Please check the updated the answer for **Spark<2.4**..!